# Nunbers in a Fixed Ratio with Same Multiset of Digits

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715219/nunbers-in-a-fixed-ratio-with-same-multiset-of-digits).

Recently I'm thinking of a problem of “magic simplifying of fractions”. Specifically, ws can simplfy “19/95” to “1/5” as we can “factor” or “cancel” out the “9”. Now I am consider the fraction of “1x/5x” and we just “factor out” the “x”. I am curious that what are the number of such number. Specifically, We want to find out how many integers $x,y$ such that:

(1) $x/y$ is a fixed ratio $p/q$.

(2) both $x$ and $y$ are $n$-digit (we allow leading zeroes.

(3) If we consider $x$ and $y$'s digits
as a multiset, they are equal. For example, $110$ and $101$ both correspond to the multiset $\{0,1^2\}$ and they are equal.

My attempt currently we can allow $O(c^n)$ such numbers for some $c>0$. For example, for ratio $1/5$, notice that $142857/714285$ is $1/5$ and we can consider $x$ to be a number sontaing $n/7$ zeros and $n/7$ sequences of $142857$. Therefore the number of such nunbers is $2^(2n/7)/\mathrm{poly}(n)$.

Now my question is, is it correct you have $10^n/\mathrm{poly}(n)$ such number pairs for all ratios $p/q$? I guess it is correct since, if $x$ is “random” then $y$ is “as random as” $x$. And two random $n$-digit number happen to have the same multiset of digits is of probability $1/\mathrm{poly}(n)$.